# Having trouble using override.aes for multiple geom_rect lines

Tags: r, ggplot2, tidyverse, facet

I am using a workaround rather than making an array to use `geom_rect` on `facets` of time series. You can see the different shading in the image below. 
[image: This image shows the two facet, CH and IT which have the variation]

The `alphas` are improper and are giving me varying shades of red. I believe this to be because the `aes` is working multiple times rather than just once but I am not sure how to overcome the problem.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Here is a snippet of my code.

```
longterm <- gather(US, value = "Rate", key = "Country",
                         US,GB,KR,AUS,DE,CN,CAN,
                         NZ,SE,IE,CH,IT,ES,DK,NL,LU,MX, 
                   data=interest)

ggplot(data = longterm, mapping = aes(x = date, y = Rate)) + 
  geom_line() + 
  facet_wrap(~ Country) + 
  labs(x = "Date", y = "Yield") + 
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent) +
  geom_rect(data = data.frame(Country = "US"), 
            aes(xmin = as.Date("2008-01-01"), 
                xmax = as.Date("2009-04-01"), 
                ymin = -Inf, ymax = Inf), 
            alpha = 0.3, fill="red", inherit.aes = FALSE) +
  geom_rect(data = data.frame(Country = "CAN"), 
            aes(xmin = as.Date("2008-07-01"), 
                xmax = as.Date("2009-06-30"), 
                ymin = -Inf, ymax = Inf), 
            alpha = 0.3, fill="red", inherit.aes = FALSE) +
  geom_rect(data = data.frame(Country = "GB"), 
            aes(xmin = as.Date("2008-04-01"), 
                xmax = as.Date("2009-06-30"), 
                ymin = -Inf, ymax = Inf), 
            alpha = 0.3, fill="red", inherit.aes = FALSE)
```

Here is the `dput(head(interest))`

```
structure(list(date = structure(c(10592, 10623, 10651, 10682, 
10712, 10743), class = "Date"), US = c(0.0472, 0.05, 0.0523, 
0.0518, 0.0554, 0.059), GB = c(0.042868, 0.044319, 0.046554, 
0.04592, 0.049068, 0.051716), KR = c(0.0753, 0.0856, 0.0823, 
0.0728, 0.0815, 0.0819), AUS = c(0.05127894737, 0.053, 0.05526521739, 
0.053575, 0.05875714286, 0.06206666667), DE = c(0.037, 0.0385, 
0.0404, 0.0385, 0.0401, 0.0436), CN = c(0.045161, 0.062767, 0.043972, 
0.043383, 0.042458, 0.034632), CAN = c(0.049465, 0.05124, 
0.05220434783, 
0.0502952381, 0.053595, 0.05580909091), NZ = c(0.0553, 0.0562, 
0.0584, 0.057, 0.0612, 0.0651), SE = c(0.0402, 0.0418, 0.0444, 
0.0424, 0.045, 0.0487), MX = c(0.3127, 0.2829, 0.251, 0.2326, 
0.2274, 0.2355), IE = c(0.0384, 0.0418, 0.041, 0.0389, 0.0434, 
0.0478), CH = c(0.02555, 0.0255, 0.02604, 0.02534, 0.0272, 0.02937
), IT = c(0.042867, 0.0428, 0.0427, 0.0411, 0.04279, 0.04615), 
ES = c(0.03880105263, 0.0402225, 0.04254391304, 0.0408635, 
0.04274238095, 0.04600090909), DK = c(0.041045, 0.042185, 
0.044317, 0.042172, 0.044605, 0.048118), NL = c(0.03801, 
0.03932, 0.04139, 0.03995, 0.04193, 0.04513), LU = c(0.0391, 
0.0393, 0.0417, 0.0401, 0.0416, 0.0437)), row.names = c(NA, 
-6L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: We need your data. what is `interest`?  you can share your data using `dput(interest)` or if it's a large dataset by `dput(head(interest))`. Please [edit] your question and add the output of aforementioned to there.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your help with the code! Will do that now

Comment: Hmm, on my first reading it looks to me like you wrote your code to avoid the problem of many overlapping rectangles.  An example dataset would allow us to help you troubleshoot.  I would recommend giving us an example of `longterm`, the data actually used in the plot, unless you think the gathering step is the one that's causing the problem.

Comment: Ok, I can do both. Just to be sure, do I post it right under the code?

Comment: BTW, you can use `longterm <- gather(US, value = "Rate", key = "Country", -date)` to exclude `date` from the gather instead of listing all the columns you want to include.

Comment: Ok, awesome. Thanks!

Comment: Do you have two `geom_rect` for Switzerland? (That seems like one of the spots with different alpha?  It seems like a cleaner approach would be to put all the shaded areas into a new table, with a variable for country, start_date, and end_date, and then call that once from inside ggplot...

Comment: I only see a problem in your plot with "CH" and "IT".  Is that right?  I can't reproduce the problem with your example data.  Are you sure you're not putting rectangles on twice for those two groups?

Comment: Ooops, yep, that was exactly my problem @aosmith! Thanks so much for your help. Really appreciate you all taking the time to answer my questions.

Comment: Personal mistake. Was layering rectangles over the same area twice.